# Need to iterate through a text file and delete/add content, preferably using Regex Replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have [this file](http://codeshare.io/TMGpI), basically I want to remove `<Placemark>` duplicates that have the same name field or address. Then I want to add a `<Data name="TELEFONO1"><value></value></Data>` void field to the `<Placemark>` tags that don't have one.

I tried using the Replace function in Notepad++ with Regex syntax, and failed:

```
<Data name="info"><value>(.*?)</value></Data>\n\t</ExtendedData>
```

REPLACE WITH:

```
<Data name="info"><value>\1</value></Data>\n\t\t<Data name="TELEFONO1"><value></value></Data>\n\t</ExtendedData>
```

It also adds the field to the ones which already have it, takes the TELEFONO1 tag into the .*?

Is there a proper way to do that? And also to remove duplicates?

Comment: share some small sample code.

Comment: Already did, [this file](http://codeshare.io/TMGpI)

Comment: You'd better use an XML Parser for such job.